# Read .png Image from a zipped file

Tags: c#, image, winforms, bitmap, zip

I am trying to get an image from a .zip archive and show it in a PictureBox.
I have a method to get text from a file inside the archive, but now I just need to get the image. I've tried different things on this site, but none seem to work for me.

Here's my code:

```
using System.Text;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string zipFileFullPath = "C:\\Tester\\adv.jar";
        string targetFileName = "pack.mcmeta";
        string text = new string(
                    (new System.IO.StreamReader(
                     ZipFile.OpenRead(zipFileFullPath)
                     .Entries.Where(x => x.Name.Equals(targetFileName,
                                                  StringComparison.InvariantCulture))
                     .FirstOrDefault()
                     .Open(), Encoding.UTF8)
                     .ReadToEnd())
                     .ToArray());
    }
}
```

Basically, I want to use the same method but instead of it being text I want it to be bitmap

Comment: This opens a text. Just check which type `ZipFile.OpenRead` returns (probably a Stream) and read from that as binary data.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [Image.FromStream()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.fromstream) to generate an Image from the [DeflateStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.deflatestream) that `ZipArchiveEntry.Open()` returns.

The overload of `Image.FromStream()` used here instructs to use ICM information (color space information) is available and skips image validation (takes a lot of time and throws anyway).

```
string zipFileFullPath = "[Some archive path]";
string imageFileName = "[Some Image file name]";

var entry = ZipFile.OpenRead(zipFileFullPath)
    .Entries.Where(x => x.Name.Equals(imageFileName, StringComparison.InvariantCulture))
    .FirstOrDefault();

Image? entryImage = null;
if (entry != null) {
    using (var stream = entry.Open()) {
        entryImage = Image.FromStream(stream, true, false);
    };
}
```

**Note (see the comments)**: the `DeflateStream` can't `Seek()` (of course). When the underlying Stream cannot seek, the `Image.FromStream()` method creates a [GPStream](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Advanced/GPStream.cs,16) (GDI+ Stream) from the source Stream using a `MemoryStream` as storage for the data coming in.
That's why, here, disposing the source Stream with a `using` statement doesn't cause the Image object to become invalid after (the Image Stream is actually a live `MemoryStream`).

---

From the example above, you should infer that there's something to fix in the existing code.

- The archive may have no entries.
- The file name you specify may not be found, so `FirstOrDefault()` returns `null`, and you're not handling this, which is going to crash you application
- There's no need of `new string()` + `string.ToArray()`. `StreamReader.ReadToEnd()` already returns the content of the file as string

Refactored:

```
string zipFileFullPath = "C:\\Tester\\adv.jar";
string targetFileName = "pack.mcmeta";

var entry = ZipFile.OpenRead(zipFileFullPath)
    .Entries?.Where(x => x.Name.Equals(targetFileName, StringComparison.InvariantCulture))
    .FirstOrDefault();

string entryTextContent = string.Empty;
if (entry != null) {
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(entry.Open(), Encoding.UTF8)) {
        entryTextContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
    };
}
```

*Here, StreamReader closes the input stream*

Comment: This is `System.Drawing` though. _All_ image-related stuff in there requires the stream to remain open as long as the image is in use. You can _never_ do anything of the type `using (var stream = ...) { myImg = Image.FromStream(stream); }` with those classes. It'll give a corrupted object that spews errors when using stuff like `.Save()` operations on it. You need to read out the bytes, put them into a `MemoryStream`, use that to initialise the image, and never dispose the `MemoryStream`.

Comment: @Nyerguds As described in the first paragraph, the Stream that `.Open()` returns is a `DeflateStream`. This Stream doesn't support `Seek`, and when the underlying Stream can't seek, `Image.FromStream()` [already creates a `MemoryStream` and copies the content of the Stream into it](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Advanced/GPStream.cs,22) (both .NET Framework and .NET)

Comment: Oh, that's very interesting to know. But, to be fair, your first paragraph does not explain that at all, that behaviour is not documented on the official specs, and in general, it is indeed a terrible idea to use any kind of `FromStream` on that class from inside a `using` block, so it's certainly something that should be explicitly explained in the answer IMO.

Comment: @Nyerguds Fair enough. I've added a note about it